# D3.nest() is finished

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I'm trying to use `nest()`in D3.js like this.

```
var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d){
    return d.ledgerID; 
  })
  .rollup(function(v){

    return {
      debit: d3.sum(v, function(b){
        return b.debit;
      }),
      credit: d3.sum(v, function(b){
        return b.credit;
      }),
    }

  })
  .entries(transactionEntries)
```

And then directly after run a loop on `data`

like this

```
    var data = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d){
            return d.ledgerID; 
        })
        .rollup(function(v){

            return {
                debit: d3.sum(v, function(b){
                    return b.deb;
                }),
                credit: d3.sum(v, function(b){
                    return b.cre;
                }),

            }
        })
        .entries(transactionEntries)

     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           console.log(data[i]);
     }
```

But it seems like the loop starts before `nest()`is completely finished which seems possible to me, so my first thought was if there is a callback or something like that I can use when `nest()` is finished?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: nest is returning the rolled up data in the `data` variable not in the transactionEntries...your for loop is called after the nest function its not async

Comment: Post a minimal example of the problematic behaviour. Be exact. What does your code do now, and what do you wish it did? A [runnable example snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would help see it.

Comment: What is your source data?  Maybe this snippet would help get you started in giving a more concrete example https://jsfiddle.net/xkn1bzgv/